# C# - Data structure that allows you to access elements based on value in range

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a list of object. They are all associated with a range which is unique to that object. There are no overlaps. I want a way to access the object associated with that range as fast as possible. None of the current data structures fit super well to the case. Here is a diagram:

```
Element 1
0.0-1.39

Element 2
1.4-2.09

Element 3
2.1-4.89

Element 4
4.9-5.0
```

What would be ideal is a kind of key/dictionary type thing where I could request the element at range value 1.7 and it would return Element 2.

The fallback is a list but that would mean iteration over it every time and depending on the size, it could theoretically get slow.

Comment: Show what you´ve tried and where you´re stuck. SO is not a code-service.

Comment: do you have holes values between elements like for ex, (1; 10), (20;35) or it's more like <10; 15), <15;23), <23; 53)?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'm not asking for code. I'm asking for information in a clear and concise manner which is absolutely what this website is about.

Comment: @Logman No holes.

Comment: Then you can use lower band as a index for dictionary. And create conversion function that will convert any number to lower band from of matched range.

Answer (score 1):

> There are no overlaps

That assumption allows you to simply store a map, where key is the lower (or upper) bound you are looking for, and find the element closest<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree)</sup> to it. This is easily achievable with tree based maps.

As side note, when you do not have that restriction and intervals can overlap - you will likely need a variation of [intervals tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

---

(1) Clarification about "closest": you need one seek: (Assuming lower bound is stored): find closest smaller/equal value. Check if it fits the range. That's done easily in logarithmic time in tree based maps.

If you store higher bound, you need to do it the other way around.

Comment: If selecting the closest element you can get whrong one also. Imagine the key is the lower bound (e.g. 1.4 for element 2). Now somecone could search for element with value 1.3, which would result to element 2 instead of 1 (as 1.3 is within the value for element 1).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Let me clarify thought it was trivial. You need one seek: (Assuming lower bound is stored): find closest smaller/equal value. Check if it fits the range. That's done easily in logarithmic time in tree based maps. Editted to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Tuple<string, double, double>> ElmList = new List<Tuple<string, double, double>>();

        private void LoadTuple()
        {

            ElmList.Add(new Tuple<string, double, double>("Element 1", 0.0, 1.39));
            ElmList.Add(new Tuple<string, double, double>("Element 2", 1.4, 2.09));
            ElmList.Add(new Tuple<string, double, double>("Element 3", 2.1, 4.89));
            ElmList.Add(new Tuple<string, double, double>("Element 4", 4.9, 5.0));

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double temp = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            var element = ElmList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item2 <= temp && x.Item3 >= temp);
            MessageBox.Show(element.Item1);
        }
```

will tuple solve your issue, i have tried something like the above

Comment: Sometimes is good to read whole question ;) "The fallback is a list but that would mean iteration over it every time and depending on the size, it could theoretically get slow."

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a search tree. You will have to group the ranges based on milestones, say for example, 1 to 5. We would then create a dictionary which would have these milstones as keys and the ranges that are closer to these milestones as values.

```
Key     Value
1       0.0-1.39
2       0.0-1.39, 1.4-2.09
3       2.1-4.89
4       2.1-4.89
5       2.1-4.89, 4.9-5.0
```

When we try to find the range in which a number falls,

1. We would do a Math.Ceil() on the number
2. Match it against the milestones in the dictionary and find the list of ranges for that key
3. Now iterate through the ranges under the milestone to find the range that contains the number

You will probably have to define the milestones differently based on the ranges you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use a binary-search-tree, or better yet an AVL (if you are not expecting a lot of inserts, or deletes).

**Sample code: Uses upper-bound values for traversal across tree** (uses AVL implementation from this [repository](https://github.com/bitlush/avl-tree-c-sharp) by [bitlush](https://bitlush.com/blog/efficient-avl-tree-in-c-sharp))

```
class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public T LBound { get; set; }

    public T UBound { get; set; }

    public bool ContainsValue(T value)
    {
        return (this.LBound.CompareTo(value) <= 0) && (value.CompareTo(this.UBound) <= 0);
    }
}

class RangeKeyComparer : IComparer<Range<double>>
{
    public int Compare(Range<double> x, Range<double> y)
    {
        return x.UBound.CompareTo(y.UBound);
    }
}

class RangeAvlTree<T, TValue> : AvlTree<Range<T>, TValue> where T : IComparable<T>
{

    public RangeAvlTree(IComparer<Range<T>> comparer)
    {
        //update access modifier to 'protected' in base class
        _comparer = comparer;
    }

    public bool Search(T searchKey, out TValue value)
    {
        //update access modifier to 'protected' in base class
        AvlNode<Range<T>, TValue> node = _root;

        while (node != null)
        {
            if (node.Key.ContainsValue(searchKey))
            {
                value = node.Value;
                return true;
            }
            else if (searchKey.CompareTo(node.Key.UBound) == 1)
                node = node.Right;
            else if (searchKey.CompareTo(node.Key.UBound) == -1)
                node = node.Left;
        }

        value = default(TValue);

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tree = new RangeAvlTree<double, string>(new RangeKeyComparer());

    tree.Insert(new Range<double> { LBound = 0.0, UBound = 1.39 }, "Element: 0.0 - 1.39");
    tree.Insert(new Range<double> { LBound = 1.4, UBound = 2.09 }, "Element: 1.4 - 2.09");
    tree.Insert(new Range<double> { LBound = 2.1, UBound = 4.89 }, "Element: 2.1 - 4.89");
    tree.Insert(new Range<double> { LBound = 4.9, UBound = 5.0 },  "Element: 4.9 - 5.00");

    string element;

    foreach(var value in new[] { 0.1, 1.41, 3, 2.04, 2.092, 4.93, 3.4 })
        if (tree.Search(value, out element))
            Console.WriteLine($"Found match: {value} matches {element}");
        else
            Console.WriteLine($"Not found: {value}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```